Solution of coupled system of differential equations
I have a system of differential equations. I would like to know if this system has an analytical solution and if yes how it looks.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
X & Y \\
Y^* & -X 
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{u}=E\mathbf{u}\,\, ,$$
where $\mathbf{u}=(u(x),v(x))^T$ and
$$X=-\frac{1}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{2m}+g$$
and
$$Y=ge^{2ix}\,\, .$$
The system has periodic boundary conditions, more specific: $u(0)=u(2\pi)$ and $v(0)=v(2\pi)$. The system doesnt look really difficult, but i couldnt find any solution (only numerical).

Is $g$ a constant?

What is the $E$ structure ?

@Cesareo I guess this is a Schrodinger equation problem in quantum mechanics. So $E$ should be the energy, which is a scalar. In other words, this is an eigenvalue equation for the matrix differential operator on the left. Since it’s self-adjoint, $E$ is real. OP should confirm all of this, of course.
